# SQL Error (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a way to loop through the table and delete everything like this, but this obviously won't work.

Let me know if you need my question worded better.

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE table1column = (SELECT table2column FROM table2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it mysql?
I often do the following. (because I can just try it with 'select' to see I got the right rows)

```
delete a.*
from table1 a
join table2 b on a.table1column = b.table2column;
```

Comment: Am I supposed to touch a and b, or just leave them? Because I didn't change them, just table1, table2, table1column and table2column.

Comment: a and b are table aliases. they can be anything uniquely identifies a table. t1 and t2 might be slightly more descriptive...

Comment: That's what I thought. The query doesn't do anything though, as I said in the first comment.

Do you know what might be the cause?

Comment: probably there's nothing matching a.table1column = b.table2column to delete?

Comment: I'm an idiot. It's because in table2column is the negative number of table1column's integer.

So table1column = 1234 and
table2column = -1234

Is there any work around for that?

Thank you for your help btw.

Comment: a.table1column = -b.table2column

Comment: Well that just makes it load incredible slow. Any advice, or should I just try to let it run?

The bar doesn't move at all.

Comment: That's something I lack. I figured out a way though. I just exported all entries from table2column and then made a DELETE FROM x WHERE -y IN(table2column entries) - thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `in` rather than `=`:

```
DELETE FROM table1
    WHERE table1column in (SELECT table2column FROM table2);
```

EDIT:

It is often faster to use `exists` with proper indexing.  The query is:

```
DELETE FROM table1
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE table2.table2column = table1.table1column);
```

You need an index on `table2(table2column)`.

Comment: or, a JOIN operation.

Comment: Or well it doesn't crash it, but the query is just 'stuck' until I cancel it.

Comment: Thank you, even though you don't get the 'Best Answer'. Both of the answers works, but user3678068 gave me some extra help I needed. (Not that I doubt you wouldn't if I had asked you).